# Chrome developer tools how to inspect mouseover css (not the hover event)?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools, web-inspector

How to inspect css gallery style (icon with hover) that appears only on mouseover event, but not appear on hover selector in dev-tools?

http://unitegallery.net/index.php?page=tiles-columns

Comment: In the upper right, on the Event LIsteners tab, click it. You'll see all the event listeners for that page and you will see mouseover midway down

Comment: Try rightclicking the element in devtools Inspector and select `:hover`, then move the mouse over the element and now the hover state should stick.

Comment: Keith, thanks for answer! But can I edit css with it like usually with :hover in css window? It seems for me that no...

Comment: WOxxOm, I tried to mark all the elements with hover, but it still dont sticks...

Comment: if its not css then no, looks like this is js that adds/remove classes

Comment: Keith, seems so, will mark you as right answer. Thank you.

Comment: Its ok, you can't mark a comment right :) . Just here to help.

Comment: WOxxom was almost write too, but there no need to select the :hover - just inspection of the place where hover suppose to be will open the hover css. It doesn't appear on screen activated, but will be editable.